# SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI Infoview Reference books

Tags: enterprise, business-objects, infoview

I'm looking for books with regards to SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI Infoview reports application, can you advise me of the best books for beginners/intermediate users?

I have located a few but I am not sure if they are the right ones for me. I have been using the application for 2 years as a front end users but need to develop my skills so that I can create reports and have a thorough understanding of the application.

Answer (score 2):

There's all sorts of documentation available which may get you up and running. I'll include a non-limiting list below.

One important thing to know upfront is the **version of BusinessObjects** you're working with. Most documentation you'll find will pertain to the most recent version: SAP BusinessObjects BI 4.1. If you're working with a previous version (e.g. XIr2 or XI 3.1), you may find that there are quite substantial differences, depending on what you part of the platform you're using.

Another remark: InfoView is a *portal*, it's not a type of report. This is a common mistake that's made, where users don't learn the proper **nomenclature**. Types of reports that are available within the BusinessObjects platform are:

- Desktop Intelligence (no longer available as of BI4)
- Web Intelligence
- Crystal Reports

There are other document types as well (e.g. Dashboards and Analysis for Office), but these are not typical "reports".

Online documentation:

- [SAP Help Portal](http://help.sap.com/bobip?current=pcat_analytics&show_children=false)
- [Official Product Tutorials](http://www.sap.com/LearnBI)

Books:

- [SAP Press's selection](https://www.sap-press.com/business-intelligence/sap-businessobjects-bi/) of books on BusinessObjects

I'll assume you're referring to Web Intelligence reports. In that case, SAP has created a new *Getting Started* guide released with recent versions of BI4 (available [here](http://help.sap.com/bowebi41?current=pcat_analytics#section4)). I would also recommend having a look at the [Official Product Tutorials related to Web Intelligence](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7819). As they are interactive, visual and split into small, specific tasks, they can help you get a basic understanding relatively fast.

If you prefer a book, then I'm sure [this book](https://www.sap-press.com/sap-businessobjects-web-intelligence_3673/) by SAP Press will contain all the information you need.

Good luck!

Comment: Superb thank you very much Kristof, I will check it all out, time to get my head down and get stuck into it...